# How do I output to multiple Cassandra column families in a single Hadoop job?

Tags: hadoop, cassandra

Cassandra data models frequently require updates to more than one column family to support a single "write" (i.e. updating both sides of a two-way index). How can I do this with Hadoop, when the job configuration only allows specifying a single output column family?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible by patching Cassandra 1.1 using the patch available at:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4208

Once you have this, instead of `ConfigHelper.setOutputColumnFamily()`, you'll call `ConfigHelper.setKeyspace()`.  Then you can use the MultipleOutputs API to specify your output CFs in the job configuration as follows:

```
MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "ColumnFamily1", ColumnFamilyOutputFormat.class, ByteBuffer.class, List.class);
MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "ColumnFamily2", ColumnFamilyOutputFormat.class, ByteBuffer.class, List.class);
```

When you're ready to output, simply reference the named CF as your output name:

```
output.write("ColumnFamily1", key, Collections.singletonList(mutation));
```

where `output` is a reference to your MultipleOutputs instance in your reducer.

Comment: If you use a current release you no longer have to patch.